# How do I select the keys from an array in PHP that are equal to some specific value?

Tags: php, arrays, select, key

for example if i have the following array:

```
$numbers=array(
"A"=>$value1,
"B"=>$value2,
"C"=>$value3,
"D"=>$value4,
"E"=>$value5,
"F"=>$value6,
"G"=>$value7,
);
```

and if some of the value variables are equal to 0 and the rest are equal to 1, how can I select the keys which values are equal, for example to 0?

Comment: You can use [array_filter](http://www.php.net/array_filter) to test any key/value and remove anything that doesn't match your test. This also works off a copy of the array so it doesn't destroy the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = [];

foreach($numbers as $id => $number) {

     if($number ==0)
         $result[$id] = $number;

}
```

Comment: this worked for me but i needed to change the first line into: $result = array();  because i was getting the following error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
Thanks!

Comment: @dream333r Sorry, [] is for arrays in newer PHP versions. 5.5 I think. I don't use anything older these days.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$all_zeros = array_filter($numbers);
$all_ones = array_diff($numbers, $all_zeros);
```

Also you might use a custom filter function like below:

```
function custom_filter($numbers, $targetValue) {
    return array_filter($numbers, function ($i) use ($targetValue) {
        return $targetValue == $i;
    });
}
```

Ref:

1. [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)
2. [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)
3. [PHP Anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)